# Can I set up a linked "linked server" without opening the firewall?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, firewall, linked-server

## My Problem

I am trying to establish a connection to a remote SQL server. Though I have a servername, port, user and password, I cannot get access. This probably means that they have some IP-restriction in their firewall settings.

Now they say that the issue will be resolved if I just add their server as a "linked server". This feature is, however, not available for a Azure SQL, so before I make major changes to my setup, I just want to make sure if this would solve anything.... so...

Does adding a "linked server" circumvent changing the firewall?
- My intuition says no...

Also, is the "server name"/"domain name" enough when connecting to a remote database, or do I also need the ip?

## Adding the linked server

link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

```
# Setting up the link
Copy
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'SERVER\NAME',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO  

#Configuring the linked server to use the domain credentials
Copy
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
    @rmtsrvname = N'SRVR002\ACCTG',   
    @locallogin = NULL ,   
    @useself = N'True' ;  
GO
```

## Retrieving SQL server IP

```
SELECT  
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a test, I removed my Azure SQL database all rules of the firewall.
[image]

Then I connect to my local SQL server and create a  linked server to Azure SQL Database, followed these tutorials: [How to create a linked server to Azure SQL Database via SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/tim/how-to-create-a-linked-server-to-azure-sql-database-via-sql-server-management-studio/) and [Create Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

I get the error message:

> Cannot open server '****' requested by the login. Client with IP address '***.***.***.**' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40615)

[image]

Then I add the client IP to the Azure SQL database firewall, linked server created successfully.

**About your two question:**

> 1. Can I set up a linked “linked server” without opening the firewall?

No, you can't. You must add the client IP to your firewall.

> 2. Is the "server name"/"domain name" enough when connecting to a remote database, or do I also need the ip?

Yes, it is. You don't need the IP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and thorough answer. Now I can push back to the guys in the organization that suggested this :)